# python only activating first elif, ignoring others

Tags: python, if-statement

```
# user input
num = int(input("Please enter engine size: "))

# calculations
if num <= 1000:
    print("The motor tax for your vehicle is €150")
elif num >= 1001 <= 1200:
    print("The motor tax for your vehicle is €175")
elif num >= 1201 <= 1400:
    print("The motor tax for your vehicle is €200")
elif num >= 1401 <= 1600:
    print("The motor tax for your vehicle is €250")
elif num >= 1601 <= 1800:
    print("The motor tax for your vehicle is €300")
elif num >= 1801 <= 2000:
    print("The motor tax for your vehicle is €350")
else:
    print("The motor tax for your vehicle is €500")
```

I know I've probably made a stupid mistake here, I'm just hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to get python to print the relevant amount for each of the specified engine size.

Each time I run it with any amount greater than `1000` it will only give me the output of `€175`.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: `elif num >= 1001 <= 1200` is not going to be doing what you are expecting. It is really evaluating `elif (num >= 1001) <= 1200` where the 1200 part is true and since num is greater then 0 and it becomes `elif True <= True`. You have to specify `elif num >= 1001 and num <= 1200` when doing your if statement logic.

Comment: Karl!!! You are an absolute angel!!!!!! Thank you so much! That works beautifully.

Comment: You can use operator chaining. But you have to do it in an other order: `1000 < num <= 1200`. Or for integers even possible: `num in range(1001, 1201)` (notice the `1201`!)

Comment: @KlausD. I actually didn't know you could chain like that. Very smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't doing what you want or expect it to be doing:

```
elif num >= 1001 <= 1200:
```

You should replace it with something like:

```
elif num in range(1001, 1201):
```

*NOTE: to check `<=`, you need to have upper bound of range incremented by 1!*

Otherwise, you could write what you originally had as:

```
elif 1001 <= num <= 1200:
```

Comment: Your range would be one off at the end `range(1001, 1200)` does not include `1200`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

i have updated the answer to PL200 to provide an answer to your question. This is a suggestion to improve a bit your code:

```
# Motor tax is based on ranges
if num <= 1000:
    tax = 150
elif num <= 1200:
    tax = 175
elif num <= 1400:
    tax = 200
elif num <= 1600:
    tax = 250
elif num <= 1800:
    tax = 300
elif num <= 2000:
    tax = 350
else:
    tax = 500
print("The motor tax for your vehicle is €{}".format(tax))
```

You actually don't need 2 inequations because of the `if` / `elif` chain.

Or you could do even better to avoid a long if/elif:

```
def get_tax(num):
    """Return the vehicle tax based on ranges"""
    # Ranges are stored as "maximum size" / "tax" 
    tax_ranges = (
        (1000, 150),
        (1200, 175),
        (1400, 200),
        (1600, 250),
        (1800, 300),
        (2000, 350),
    )
    default_tax = 500

    for max_size, tax in tax_ranges:
        if num <= max_size:
            return tax
    return default_tax

num = int(input("Please enter engine size: "))
print(f"The motor tax for your vehicle is {get_tax(num)}")
```

*NOTE: I added a `f-string` at the end to print but it might not supported by your version of Python if you have a version earlier than 3.6. In that case, just replace `{get_tax(num)}` by `"... {}".format(get_tax(num))` and remove the `f` before the string*